# Google Sheets Script -> .setActiveSheet() does not work

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following script:

```
function UpdateAllSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheetslength = sheets.length;
  for (var n=0; n < sheetslength; n++) {
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[n]);
  TotalDayUpdate();
  }
}
```

The script above should run through all sheets of the Spreadsheet and run the function TotalDayUpdate() for each one of them.

But it gives an error:

Specified sheet must be part of the spreadsheet. (for line: SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[n]);)

I have an older Spreadsheet that the same function works without error.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not a solution, but should be more clear:

```
function UpdateAllSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var n=0; n < sheets.length; n++) {
    TotalDayUpdate(sheets[n]); // directly give the sheet as argument to the function
  }
}
```

so in your TotalDayUpdate function as you have the parsed sheet in parameter you could use it. For me it's better because you don't call SpreadsheetApp... again what is time consuming

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is not a solution, but it is indeed more clear.